# Why do people claim Tails is more secure than Windows?

Tags: tor

Why do some people say that using Tor within my normal operating system will not be safe? What differentiates Windows and Tails in this regard?

I believe that running Windows together with a VM, VPN and Tor is safe. If that is not the case, what makes Tails superior?

Comment: *"What is difference between windows vs tails?"* - these are different things designed for different purposes. One is a universal system designed to run everything, the other is a specialized system to do only a few things right. *"I think ... . If I'm wrong, please explain to me why."* - You make a broad claim without any kind of proof and then ask others to prove you wrong? That's not how it works - you are making a claim so  please explain your reasoning behind your claim instead. *"...  is safe"* - safe from what?

Answer (score 2):

From the networking perspective it doesn't make much difference whether you use Tails or Windows/Linux; Tor protects the source of the traffic equally.

From the OPSEC perspective Tails is better, because it lacks persistence, as explained in [How Tails works](https://tails.boum.org/about/index.en.html):

> Tails always starts from the same clean state and everything you do
> disappears automatically when you shut down Tails.
>
> Without Tails, almost everything you do can leave traces on the computer:

Additionally, with Tor you should avoid standing out in a crowd. If you create something customized by yourself rather than using standard tools you might be vulnerable to *browser fingerprinting*. Whether using Tails or not, you should at least use the Tor browser and update it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The main "security" (I'd rather say anonymity ) difference between tails and Windows is in term of Hardware : Tails does not save anything on your HDD, everything is saved on RAM and when you shutdown your OS, you'll erase/recover your RAM's data. So, if someone gets your computer after you've shutdown it, it is supposed to be impossible to get any information.

As said before, in term of network it's supposed to be similar.

Comment: In addition to not leaving tracks on a particular computer, Tails also maintains no information between sessions.  No Tracking Cookies, No Super Cookies, & Generic window settings to help avoid fingerprinting.